# Why asking for a +1 in an UPDATErequest does a +2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using php+5 and MySQL.

Here's the thing : I'm trying to add "a view" for an element on my database.
To do so, I wrote :

```
 $req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE table SET views = views+1 WHERE id = :id');
 $work = $req->execute(array(':id' => $id));
```

With that, it strangely adds TWO views to my entry. If I had "6" in the table, I get a "8" after running this code.
I can't figure out why the hell it doesn't add 1. I tried adding 2, and in this case it adds 4 instead....

I checked and tried many things.

For informations

- this code is running just once (and not twice as we could think)
- the type of "views" in the database is "INT"

Thx for your answers and your help....

### UPDATE

Sorry for your lost of time guys.
My code is actually executing twice, and it appears it's because of my .htaccess and my url_rewriting thing.

I'm doing something like :

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)? /index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Cause I'm trying something with slugs. And obviously, the page is loading twice because of that.
Any idea why ?

Sorry again -_-

Comment: your code is executing twice. you'll have to figure out why.

Comment: I was gonna say "I'm telling you it does not !!"
Then I test with a request that insert time(); in my database. And it actually executes twice.....
Meh, screw this. Sorry for your lost of time guys

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for your lost of time guys.
My code is actually executing twice, and it appears it's because of my .htaccess and my url_rewriting thing.

I'm doing something like :

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)? /index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Cause I'm trying something with slugs. And obviously, the page is loading twice because of that.
Any idea why ?

Sorry again -_-

Comment: A browser requests for favicon? Just check the access log and see for sure.